# Weird JS flow in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, control-flow

My JS code is as follows

```
if (fileControl != NoFileMessage) {
    if (fileControl.val() != NoFileMessage) {
        var valid_extensions = /(.xlsx)$/i;
        if (!valid_extensions.test(fileControl.val())) {
            alert($("#txtInvalidFileFormatMsg").val());
            return false;
        }
...
    }
}
```

During first execution the `alert` is shown and then the control "jumps back" to the first `if` statement instead of continuing to `return false`, due to which the code is executed twice and the `alert` is shown twice

Due to this, the alert box is shown twice. Any pointers on how I can fix this? It's working fine in other browsers (including IE !)

**UPDATE:**
Some more insight, this piece of code is being called on the `.change()` event of a `<input type='file />'`

As I've stated earlier, the code snippet is executed twice, after some digging in, I figured out that the `.change()` event is being fired twice. Why does this happen in FX only?

Comment: Add a `console.log()` before the first `if` statement, and see if it's logged twice.

Comment: Are you binding the same event to an element twice by mistake?

Comment: @AlexeyLebedev it is getting logged twice

Comment: @TommyBs this is someone else's code, so that will take sometime to hunt, but as I said it's working fine in other browsers.. could that be the issue?

Comment: @badZoke then the control doesn't jump back. The function's getting called twice. You can look at the call stack and find where the problem is coming from.

Comment: @AlexeyLebedev cool, got it .. it's getting called from elsewhere. Thanks:)

Comment: @AlexeyLebedev why is this an issue only in FX?

Comment: @badZoke it doesn't happen for me in FX: http://jsfiddle.net/dNQKv/

Comment: Hmm, I've added a `flag` to "force" the event to fire only once, this after `.stopPropagation()` and `.stopImmediatePropagation()` failed. Will update an answer if I find a proper solution..  Thanks for the help